# Is it neccessary to manually dispose?

Tags: flutter

I heard that if you create something, for example `AnimationController`, you have to manually dispose it or it will cause memory leak.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
```

Is it still need to do this in today version (2.10.3)?

If it still need, which class I need to manually dispose, how do I know that?

Comment: `Is it still need to do this in today version (2.10.3)` Yes, sometimes animation still running when widget is disposed. `If it still need, which class I need to manually dispose, how do I know that?` simply dispose each class which have dispose method.
Btw, you need to call `_controller.dispose();` before `super.dispose()`.

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך
Thanks for anwser. Can you explain more about 'sometimes'?

Comment: For example, when running a moving object animation from left to right screen, it will keep running in the background for a while until its duration is finished eventhough we have  go to another screen. It will keep using a portion of a memory until it is finished or disposed.